# An unexpected 'possible division by zero' when values are known to be positive

Tags: divide-by-zero, theorem-proving, dafny

I want to prove the following property in Dafny: if a division `(a+k)/(b+k)` is smaller or equal than `1`; then if `a` is smaller than `-k`, the division `(a+k)/(b+k)` is now greater or equal than `-1`.

For instance, given `a=2`,`b=3` and `k=0.1`, we have `2+0.1/3+0.1 <= 1`. But if `a=-2`, which holds to be smaller than `-k=-0.1`, then  `-1 <= -2+0.1/3+0.1`.

Thus, I consider the following lemma:

```
lemma boundDivision (a:real, b:real, k:real)
  requires k>=0.0 && b>=0.0
  requires a <= b;
  //requires b+k >=0.0
  ensures (a+k)/(b+k) <= 1.0 ==> (a<-k ==> (-1.0 <= (a+k)/(b+k)))
  {
    //assert b+k>=0.0;
  }
```

It does not automatically verify, but what actually makes me confused is the fact that Dafny warns `possible division by zero` in `(a+k)/(b+k)`. I mean, both `b` and `k` are non-negative...

What am I missing? How can I verify this?

**EDIT**

It turns out I was keeping k non-negative, instead of strictly positive which was, indeed, its usage. I am leaving my question in case someone can help me prove the property. Code is now as follows:

```
lemma boundDivision (a:real, b:real, k:real)
  requires k>=0.0 && b>=0.0
  requires a <= b;
  //requires b+k >=0.0
  ensures (a+k)/(b+k) <= 1.0 ==> (a<-k ==> (-1.0 <= (a+k)/(b+k)))
  {
    //assert b+k>=0.0;
  }
```

Comment: Both `b` and `k` are *non-negative*.

Comment: …so in particular they can be both zero.

Comment: You mean I should use non-negative instead of positive? Modified!

Comment: Oh.. true.. indeed k should be strictly positive :) Silly mistake of mine!! I am leaving the question so that anyone can help me prove this. Does the property seem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property seems wrong. If you use VSCode, right-click and ask for counter examples.
You might need to add more assertions to ensure the counter-examples are meaningful, but consider:

```
a = -3
b = 0
k = 1
```

Then your postcondition does not hold

Comment: Yep, I missed the precondition '-b <= a'. Sorry for the silly question, at least I learnt about counter example showing eheheh Thanks!!